# How to display the name and the email from GoogleSignInResult object with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have created an app in which a have added a Firebase and Google authentication.

```
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                //
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

When i click the `Google Sign In` button, i'm logged in correctly into my account. But when is try to display the name and the email of the person, once it is signed in, i get an error. I'm using in this code in my `onActivityResult` method, and `acct` is always `null`. Where am i wrong?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(getIntent());
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount(); //null
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        System.out.println(personName + " / " + personEmail);
    }
}
```

This is the error: `ATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity ..... java.lang.NullPointerException`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On Debugging firstly see `data` has some value in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: `data` has a value: `I/System.out: Intent { (has extras) }`. Only the `acct` it's `null`.

Comment: Don't print `data` value.Debug your app and Place a breakpoint on `super.onActivityResult` line and find out value of `requestCode` , `resultCode` and `data` .

Comment: The `data` and the `requestCode` are ok. The `resultCode` has the value of `-1`. What is happening?

Comment: `resultCode ` =-1 means result is Ok .If `data` is not null can you see in debugging value for `data.getExtras` or try every suggestion on evaluating `data` while debugging.ou will surely get something in `data`.

Comment: For me seems to be ok but it's not. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Here is my tutorial on google plus login coderzpassion.com/android-working-latest-google-plus-login-api/ .You can try this.

Comment: Also, you can check this out https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L135-L153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to  be that you are passing the `getIntent` as an argument to `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(getIntent());`  here `getIntent()` returns activity intent. you should replace `getIntent()` with `data` from `onActivityResult` :

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
```

Also add `RESULT_OK` as:

```
 if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the same error, even if i change as you said.

Answer (score -1):

It feels that the sign-in was not successful. Try checking resultCode == RESULT_OK along with the request code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can i do that?

Comment: @Majeed Khan you can see error log posted by @Alex M. where `result=-1` which means `resultCode==RESULT_OK` that's already true.